# How graceless is shutdown?

Tags: shutdown

Shutting down the machine from the command line with e.g. `shutdown -h` seems as if it would not be particularly graceful, but on a scale of "Pulling the power cord out of the wall" to "Going through the standard shutdown procedure from the  Menu", how graceless is `shutdown -h` actually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely prefer `shutdown -h` to pulling the power cord out of the wall. [`shutdown`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/shutdown.8.html) provides an opportunity for macOS to cleanly exit important underlying processes and flush file caches to storage.

### Avoid `shutdown`

Having [implemented a gentle shutdown programmatically](https://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2012-04-16-shutting-down-your-mac-safely/), experience taught us that you should try to avoid `shutdown -h` when you have logged in users and running graphical Mac applications:

> `shutdown` is a blunt tool that will in most cases shut down your Mac. It works at a layer below the Mac's user interface and is roughly the equivalent of force quitting everything.
>
> With `shutdown`, Mac applications that would have quit nicely are not given the chance. In most cases using shutdown should be fine but care needs to be taken about denying applications of the opportunity to quit nicely.

– [Shutting Down Your Mac Safely](https://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2012-04-16-shutting-down-your-mac-safely/), dssw.co.uk

### Prefer `kAEShutDown`

If you are able, follow Apple's advice in [Technical Q&A QA1134 - Programmatically causing restart, shutdown and/or logout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1134/_index.html). This advice can be summed up as: issue an `kAEShutDown` AppleEvent to the system.

Be aware that using only `kAEShutDown` has its limitations, these are discussed in [How to Shut Down Your Mac Using AppleScript](https://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2010-09-09-how-to-shut-down-your-mac-using-applescript/).

#### By AppleScript or Command Line

You can use an AppleScript snippet to issue the `kAEShutDown` using:

```
tell application "Finder"
    shut down
end tell
```

Or using the command line tool `osascript`:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to shut down'
```

### Counter to the macOS Approach

In terms of non-graphical processes, `shutdown` is reasonable. For anything graphical or at the user level, you should avoid it. Issuing `shutdown` is not appropriate for regular use on macOS; as an emergency measure it is fine but not as a pre-considered solution.

Users would quickly learn to avoid an application that simply issued `shutdown` instead of issuing the request through the AppleEvent.

Comment: Let's say I wanted to issue a kAEShutDown from the command line, how could that be done? (Short of writing a short snippet of code, compiling it and running it, I mean.)

Comment: In terms of system services and so on, though, shutdown is somewhat, if not entirely considerate?

Comment: So if a single process hangs the graphical shell, then `shutdown` can be issued without risk of deeper injury?

Comment: These are better asked as [new questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Feel free to refer to this question in your new questions.